# Prove/Disprove: If $T$ is diagonalizable, then $T^n$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Prove/Disprove: Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space, and let $T : V → V$ be a linear transformation.

If $T$ is diagonalizable, then $T^n$ is diagonalizable, for some $n \in\mathbb{R}$.

I think this one is true:

If $T$ is is diagonalizable, then there exists a basis $B$ such that $[T]_B$ is a diagonal matrix.

So, $[T^n]_B=([T]_B)^n$ is also diagonal (power of a diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix),

so there exists a basis for V such that the matrix representation of $T^n$ is also diagonal, so $T^n$ is diagonalizable.

Is that correct?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Whenever you need to prove something for a diagonalisable operator, a natural thing to do is to look what it means when expressed on  basis of diagonalisation (in other words, what does it mean for diagonal matrices). You did that, and it worked, +1.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $T$ is diagonalisable means there exists an invertible $P$ such that $PTP^{-1}=D,$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. We need to show that there exists an invertible $Q$ such that $QT^nQ^{-1}=\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal. Note that
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
PT^nP^{-1} &= (PTP^{-1})(PTP^{-1})...(PTP^{-1}) \\
&=D^n,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
and as you pointed out, a diagonal matrix raised to a power is also diagonal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $M$ is diagonalizable if and only if $M$ is similar to diagonal matrix. i.e. $M \equiv D$, where $D$ is diagonal matrix. So $M^n = M×M×...×M = D'$(diagonal matrix). (Product of diagonal matrices is a diagonal matrix and diagonal matrix is diagonalizable.)

Comment: Cool, thank you!